# Postgresql error in proximity calculation for latitude longitude

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, latitude-longitude, haversine

I have a table of airport data imported from here in postgresql: http://ourairports.com/data/

Here's the DDL

```
create table flights.airports
(
id integer not null
    constraint airports_pkey
        primary key,
ident varchar(7) not null,
type varchar(14) not null,
name varchar(77) not null,
latitude_deg numeric(25,22) not null,
longitude_deg numeric(22,18) not null,
elevation_ft integer,
continent varchar(2) not null,
iso_country varchar(2) not null,
iso_region varchar(7) not null,
municipality varchar(60),
scheduled_service varchar(3) not null,
gps_code varchar(4),
iata_code varchar(3),
local_code varchar(7),
home_link varchar(128),
wikipedia_link varchar(128),
keywords varchar(256),
feed_url varchar(255),
created_at date,
input_line_num integer,
geom geometry(Point,4326)
)
;
```

Here's an example of the data:

```
id  ident   type    name    latitude_deg    longitude_deg   elevation_ft    continent   iso_country iso_region  municipality    scheduled_service   gps_code    iata_code   local_code  home_link   wikipedia_link  keywords
6523    00A heliport    Total Rf Heliport   40.07080078 -74.93360138    11  NA  US  US-PA   Bensalem    no  00A     00A         
6524    00AK    small_airport   Lowell Field    59.94919968 -151.6959991    450 NA  US  US-AK   Anchor Point    no  00AK        00AK            
6525    00AL    small_airport   Epps Airpark    34.8647995  -86.77030182    820 NA  US  US-AL   Harvest no  00AL        00AL            
6526    00AR    closed  Newport Hospital & Clinic Heliport  35.6087 -91.254898  237 NA  US  US-AR   Newport no                      00AR
```

I'm using the following PostgreSQL Haversine query to return the closest airports to a given Lat / Lon value:

```
SELECT * FROM flights.airports WHERE acos(sin(38.691055) * sin(latitude_deg) + cos(38.691055) * cos(latitude_deg) * cos(longitude_deg - (-121.233055))) * 6371 <= 1000;
```

source: http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

The values that I've put into the query above (38.691055,-121.233055) are a point near MC CLELLAN AIRFIELD (Sacramento).

`https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/38°41'27.8"N+121°13'59.0"W/@38.691055,-121.3731307,11z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d38.691055!4d-121.233055?hl=en`

However, when I run my query the select returns the following data,

MYERS FIELD,39.8849983215332,-86.50669860839844

Which is in Indiana, note the difference in the longitude.

`https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Myers+Field,+Lizton,+IN,+USA/38.691055,-121.233055/@39.8910608,-112.8731208,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m8!4m7!1m5!1m1!1s0x886cb47c5293f51b:0x29b57085edb34681!2m2!1d-86.5066666!2d39.8850438!1m0?hl=en`

I've tested the CSV data and it is good, I've checked out the haversine query and it looks to be a standard approach, so I'm assuming that the problem is the way that I'm storing / presenting the latitude and longitude values, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The formula in the link you have provided use radians. In your query, you are using degrees.
Try converting the units of all your lat and long, using the `radian()` function.
Also you swapped the last long1 and long2 in the formula.

```
SELECT * 
FROM flights.airports 
WHERE acos(
       sin(radians(38.691055)) 
         * sin(radians(latitude_deg)) 
       + cos(radians(38.691055)) 
         * cos(radians(latitude_deg)) 
         * cos( radians(-121.233055)
           - radians(longitude_deg))
       ) * 6371 <= 1000;
```

Comment: Sadly that didn't work either. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: @sadly: ah, the last two longitudes are not in the same order in your attempt as in the source equation. Try the updated solution

Comment: Its still not right, there must be something I'm doing wrong with the way I'm storing the lat / long of the airports data, because the query for find the closest airport to `38.691055`, `-121.233055` returns the following:

`MC MANUS FIELD`,`33.4522018433`,`-96.8328018188,695`

Comment: The correct answer is

`MC CLELLAN AIRFIELD`,`38.66759872`,`-121.401001`

Comment: Adding the missing closing parentheses (just before *6371), the above equation return 2261km to 33.4522018433,-96.8328018188